# Comparing two binsearches from K&R (array indices vs pointers)

Tags: c

My question is below the code.

There are two different bin searches in K&R described in the chapter on structures, one uses array indices to work with the structure (p. 134) and another uses a pointer to the structure (p. 136).

The binsearch decides whether a particular string in the structure, `keytab[n].word`, matches a string in an array, `word`.

Here is the structure declaration itself with an initialization of it. The struct holds a bunch of c keyboards and the number of times they occur.

```
    struct key {
       char *word;
       int count;
   } keytab[] = {
       "auto", 0,
       "break", 0,
       "case", 0,
       "char", 0,
       "const", 0,
       "continue", 0,
       "default", 0,
       /* ... */
       "unsigned", 0,
       "void", 0,
       "volatile", 0,
       "while", 0
   };
```

Here is the first binsearch

```
/* binsearch:  find word in tab[0]...tab[n-1] */
   int binsearch(char *word, struct key tab[], int n)
   {
       int cond;
       int low, high, mid;

       low = 0;
       high = n - 1;
       while (low <= high) {
           mid = (low+high) / 2;
           if ((cond = strcmp(word, tab[mid].word)) < 0)
               high = mid - 1;
           else if (cond > 0)
               low = mid + 1;
           else
               return mid;
       }
       return -1;
   }
```

Here is the binsearch using pointers to the structure instead of array indices:

```
/* binsearch: find word in tab[0]...tab[n-1] */
   struct key *binsearch(char *word, struct key *tab, int n)
   {
       int cond;
       struct key *low = &tab[0];
       struct key *high = &tab[n];
       struct key *mid;

       while (low < high) {
           mid = low + (high-low) / 2;
           if ((cond = strcmp(word, mid->word)) < 0)
               high = mid;
           else if (cond > 0)
               low = mid + 1;
           else
               return mid;
       }
       return NULL;
   }
```

There are two things I don't understand.

First, let's assume that n is the size of the struct array in both cases.

In the first binsearch, `n-1` is described as the uppermost limit of the search. The matching string can actually occur in `tab[high = n-1].word`, but not in `tab[n].word`.

In the second binsearch, the uppermost limit is written as `struct key *high = &tab[n]`, as if the string can occur there, even though "it is illegal to dereference" it (p.138, top). It should be a `NULL` pointer.

Why isn't this written as `struct key *high = &tab[n-1]`? Array stuff like this always seems to confuse me in c.

The second thing I don't understand is

`high = mid;`

in the second binsearch as opposed to

`high = mid -1;`

In the second binsearch.

Why isn't the second one `high = mid-1` as well?

Comment: There's another difference which is closely related: `while(low <= high)` in the first, versus `while(low < high)` in the second.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is that with pointer subtraction, you are getting the result of subtracting the offsets, IE if `low = &tab[0]` and `high = &tab[n-1]`, the result of `high - low` is `n-1` rather than `n`.  To get the midpoint you need `n` though (`n/2`), so `high` should be equal to `&tab[n]`.  The answer to the second question is that mid will always be one higher than the elements you are interested in (since we know it is not the answer already, and all elements above it are not), so it is now one past the end of the portion of the array you are interested in.  Thus, the first question's logic applies and we leave our high point at one past the "end" of our array.

Answer (score 1):

> In the second binsearch, the uppermost limit is written as struct key *high = &tab[n], as if the string can occur there, even though "it is illegal to dereference" it (p.138, top). It should be a NULL pointer.

No, it will *not* be a null pointer.  It will be a pointer to the first address beyond the end of the array.  You cannot dereference `high`, but you can use it in pointer arithmetic.

> Why isn't this written as struct key *high = &tab[n-1]?

Because the arithmetic works out simpler if you let `high` point one element past the actual upper bound.

> Why isn't the second one high = mid-1 as well?

Because they've chosen to have `high` point one element past the actual upper bound.  This is just to be consistent.

You can write the pointer version just like the index version, where high points to the actual element, but you'll find that you need `+1` and `-1` adjustments here and there.  They way they've chosen to do this eliminates most of those.